# Firebase cloud functions init not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to use Firebase cloud functions but when I try to init exists project I get error.
This is the error "**Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission**"

I created project before and then I moved project folder. When I had tried deploy, it wasn't work. I don't remember which error I got. And then I tried init same project but I got this error.

I tried logout and login again but it wasn't work.
I deleted "firebase-tools" but it wasn't work too.
And after I tried on different computer and I got same error.

And also I have Firebase Admin permission.

Comment: You probably want to run `firebase init --debug` to see more details about the error. Where is the error triggered? What is the call that is failing? Is it calling the API in the right project?

Answer (score 2):

The firebase init command initializes/enables the project to use Cloud Functions for Firebase. Owners or Editors should use this command. Owners/Editors have higher permissions which allows APIs to be enabled (e.g. allowing the project to create VMs, Cloud Functions, or create a NoSQL Database).

Therefore I think you should perform this operation with Owner/Editor role.

Comment: Hi marian. I am in a situation were client cannot give me owner or editor role for security reason. Is there any other way to achieve same ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `Owner` or `Editor` IAM permission on the GCP project to use `firebase init` command.

The firebase init command initializes/enables the project to use Cloud Functions/Hosting for Firebase. Owners/Editors have higher permissions that allow APIs to be enabled etc.

it is a first-time task when you starting the development, and then init command can be avoided if you have set up your cloud functions code in VCS for multiple developers or you.

i.e, Usually after writing code, you will replicate the project to other developers, who will then also write code and use `firebase use yourprojectid` further.