# HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to enable service [artifactregistry.googleapis.com]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My firebase account has following permissions `Firebase admin`, `Cloud functions admin` and `Service account user` but when I tried to deploy my function it gave the following error:

```
HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to enable service [artifactregistry.googleapis.com]
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with permissions, since according to [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase),
I have the required IAM permissions to deploy. Not sure whats causing this error

Comment: Are you currently impersonating a service account?  What is the output of `gcloud config get-value account` and `gcloud auth list`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase cloud functions init not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328533/firebase-cloud-functions-init-not-working)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue in the end?

Comment: Yes, my bad for not posting.
You have to enable Artifact Registry API in your project https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest